# Jquery Mobile opacity doesn't work :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to make this button pulsate on jQuery mobile?

Are there problems with jQuery mobile because in my main application on some divs I can apply this pulsating effect and on other they just flicker, or fade in and out with interruptions or it jerky fades in and out.

html:

```
<button id="pulsate">I want to pulsate!</button>
```

JS:

```
    $('#pulsate').on('click', function () {
        pulsate("#pulsate");
    });


function pulsate(element) { 
    $(element || this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() { 
       $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500, pulsate); }); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alecstheone/zCUSK/

I only use jquery and jquerymobile... I noticed that if I disable jquerymobile in jsfiddle it works but I dont want this as I use jquerymobile in my application for other things...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but you've to make some changes to your script, As you're having a click event on the button but using jQuery mobile your button is wrapped around with `span` and `divs`(mainly because of jquery mobile css),

So you just have to traverse through that target div with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to set your animation effect. 
 Below is the small demo of your code with the desired effects.

```
$('#pulsate').on('click', function () {
    pulsate(this); // Change here
});

function pulsate(element) {
    $(element || this).closest("div.ui-btn").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).closest("div.ui-btn").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500, pulsate);
    });
}
```

[**<kbd>Fiddle Example</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCUSK/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I noticed that you used "div.ui-btn". This is a part of my phonegap application: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/D4UqU/12/ I just want to make it pulse when its undes 20%. It works fine on fiddle. But on the phone it just fades out once correctly and than it fades out immediatly without delay and it just stays there. Is there a simmilar problem ? Do I need to use closest or something like that? Im new and Im trying since weeks to get it working. If you dont know phonegap please tell me another ways to achive this effect.. Maybe others will work.. Thank you!

Comment: No you don't have to use `closest()`, i just went through your scenario and it works just fine for me in browser and sorry about phonegap i don't have much idea about it! And code works perfectly it's toggling as expected under 20% in progress bar

Comment: but are there other ways to achieve this effect? Maybe others will work also on the device...

Comment: Hold on a min! I have an idea!

Comment: @AlexStanese Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D4UqU/14/), I have used `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` Hope it will also work with jQuery Mobile and phonegap!

Comment: I tried that but instead of smooth fade in and out it just fades in and out directly. (something like either opacity 0 either opacity 1 )

Comment: @AlexStanese Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D4UqU/16/), used [`.fadeTo()`](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/fadeTo/index.html)

Comment: still the same result :(